# How to create a "top-level collection" for a Racket package?

Tags: package, racket

I'm trying to create an installable Racket package I can put on the web.  I am following the [instructions for developing packages](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/how-to-create.html) from the Racket documentation.  However, when I create a package following these instructions, I get the error

```
raco setup: error: during making for <user>/handin50/tufts-comp50-2013f (COMP 50)
raco setup:   *** Error: this collection must be a top-level collection
```

I cannot find the concept of *creating* a top-level collection in the documentation.

The particular package I am trying to create is a copy of the handin client, as described in the documentation for the handin server.  Unfortunately I cannot link to a copy of this documentation online; the handin server is at https://github.com/plt/handin and the documentation source is at https://github.com/plt/handin/blob/master/handin-server/scribblings/client-customization.scrbl

I would be grateful for any pointer explaining how to create a top-level collection or any other workaround.

Comment: Which version of Racket are you using?

Comment: What's the command that produces the error? Is it raco pkg create? I tried a bunch of variations and I couldn't produce the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A top-level collection is an immediate sub-directory of a collection root like the Racket installation's `collects/` directory. Some examples of top-level collections are `racket`, `db`, and `rackunit`.

If I'm reading the error right, it's complaining because `tufts-comp50-2013f` is a sub-collection (ie, sub-directory) of `handin50`; the latter is the top-level collection in this case. The solution is to move `tufts-comp50-2013f` one directory up.

The error appears to be coming from this source file: https://github.com/plt/handin/blob/master/handin-client/this-collection.rkt in the `this-name-stx` macro. The comments assert that the code needs to be in its own top-level collection directory, but doesn't really explain why.